# Azure Maps - IconOptions - image - 'marker-green'

Tags: azure-maps

There is no built-in option for a 'green-marker' in the image property of the IconOptions.

How do I go about implementing one?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.iconoptions?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an image to the map image sprite. There are templates for all the built in icons and more as shown here: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=All%20built-in%20icon%20templates%20as%20symbols

You can load a template into the map and display it in a symbol layer as shown in this sample: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Symbol%20layer%20with%20built-in%20icon%20template

Here is sample that uses the "marker" icon template, and gives it a green color.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Symbol layer with built-in icon template - Azure Maps Web SDK Samples</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map, datasource;
        
        function GetMap() {
            //Initialize a map instance.
            map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                view: 'Auto',

                //Add authentication details for connecting to Azure Maps.
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: '<Your Azure Maps Key>'
                }
            });

            //Wait until the map resources are ready.
            map.events.add('ready', function () {
                //Create a data source to add your data to.
                datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
                map.sources.add(datasource);

                //Add a point to the center of the map.
                datasource.add(new atlas.data.Point([0, 0]));

                //Create an icon from one of the built-in templates and use it with a symbol layer.
                map.imageSprite.createFromTemplate('myTemplatedIcon', 'marker', 'green', '#fff').then(function () {

                    //Add a symbol layer that uses the custom created icon.
                    map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
                        iconOptions: {
                            image: 'myTemplatedIcon'
                        }
                    }));
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```